# Array as value of OPC node to SiteWise Assets

Tags: amazon-web-services, opc, aws-iot-greengrass, aws-iot-sitewise

I have an OPC server that has nodes with arrays as values. For example I have a node called "Temperatures" which has values `[33, 29, 30, 19]` in the array.

**Is it possible to set single items of this array as properties into SiteWise assets with aliases** like `/Temperatures/1`, `/Temperatures/2`, `/Temperatures/3`, etc.?